# How to assign a Javascript variable to the same value of another variable

Tags: javascript

How do you make a Javascript value have the same value as another variable. I have a variable called "buttonId", and another called "toWin", I want to make it so that buttonId's value doesn't change, but, toWin changes to have the same value as buttonId. something like:

```
toWin=buttonId;
```

Can anyone help me? No jQuery, please.

Comment: Your code seems correct, although you should use `var` when declaring new variables. Are those objects or variables?

Comment: Yes, I checked the spelling on both variables

Comment: What's the *actual* problem? The assignment operator is how to do this. Are you instead having an issue with changing one object and the otherone *also* changes, e.g., two references to the same object?

Comment: @CPC Sergio asked if they were objects or variables, not if they were spelled correctly.

Comment: You mean whenever buttonId changes, toWin automatically changes also?? Or do you actually mean an HTML buttons's value??

Comment: possible duplicate of [Most elegant way to clone a JavaScript object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/728360/most-elegant-way-to-clone-a-javascript-object)

Comment: @CPC if these are objects, changing one will change the other. You might want to clone/copy them instead.

Comment: I'm kind of new at programming, and I was a little confused at what the definition of an object is, but I googled it, and realized that it actually isn't an object.

Comment: I figured out what is wrong with it, I had a different problem, this wasn't the problem at all, so I don't really need help anymore, but thanks

Comment: @CPC please post the solution as an answer and accept your own answer so that future visitors can get help as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just like you have it, but if you're declaring it for the first time, use the var keyword.

`var toWin = buttonId;`

If `buttonId` is an object, you may want to clone the object before setting `toWin` to the value of `buttonId` to avoid changing the value of the original object (`buttonId`) when and if you change `toWin`.

Comment: Hmm, I was just debugging something, and thought that that might not work, so I just checked on here if it does, so I guess I have a different problem.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to mention var while declaring the second variable. you should do it like this:

```
var something = '1'; 
var anotherthing = something;

alert(anotherthing);
```

The output will be 1.

Comment: I was just debugging something, and thought that that might not work, so I just checked on here if it does, so I guess I have a different problem.

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
toWin=buttonId;
```

I was debugging my Javascript, and thought that this might be the problem, so I just checked on here if it works, but now I know that my problem is completely different.